# How to measure timing of mulitple ajax calls if javascript is single threaded

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var ajaxResponseTime1;
var ajaxResponseTime2;

$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        ajaxResponseTime1= new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        //some task that takes 5 seconds
    }
});

$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        //possibly inaccurate since it includes the time it took to 
        //execute other success callback function
        ajaxResponseTime2= new Date().getTime() - startTime;  

        //some task that takes 5 seconds
    }
});
```

Since javascript is single threaded, doesn't that mean that whichever success method gets called first, the time it took to execute that success method will be figured into the time it took the 2nd success callback function to be called?

I want to know the time it took each ajax call to call the success callback.  As in the response time.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on what data you're fetching?

Comment: You could try using a deferred object to defer execution of code until each response time has been logged.

Comment: if you're doing this for debugging purposes, just use the developer tools in chrome/firefox/IE (and im sure opera and safari have them too) and look at the network tab

Comment: @c--misura, yes it does...and that's what I'm trying to get accurately.

Comment: I would do something like @MBottens suggested - use 2 deferred objects , and then you could perform some action when they both resolve, or one or the other resolves

Comment: @c--misura, so to get accurate timing I would have to give up the advantage of async calls.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of a concrete way to get the timing precise (consistently)

Comment: Whatever you end up with, don't use `new Date().getTime();` or `+new Date;` but [`Performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) instead.

Comment: @nietonfir Unfortunately I have to support IE7, but otherwise yes Performance.now() is more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var ajaxResponseTime1;
var ajaxResponseTime2;
var executeTime = 0; 

$.ajax({
    success: function(){
    ajaxResponseTime1= new Date().getTime() - startTime - executeTime;
    //some task that takes 5 seconds
    executeTime = new Date().getTime() - ajaxResponseTime1;
  }
});

$.ajax({
    success: function(){
    ajaxResponseTime2= new Date().getTime() - startTime - executeTime;  
    //some task that takes 5 seconds
    executeTime = new Date().getTime() - ajaxResponseTime2;
 } 
});
```

Now the execution time of any other callbacks is considered when getting the response time.

Comment: Ok, I misread your `//some task that takes 5 seconds`. I thought you were referring to the response time of the ajax call. :-(. So what you're saying is that you're going to be running a synchronous script which is going to take 5 seconds to execute?

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-editing this answer now that I have more of an understanding of how you're approaching your question.

The term ***accuracy*** is obviously relative. The two ajax calls are called less than a millisecond apart on most modern processors. Consider this code:

```
var start = new Date.getTime();

display();

function display(){ console.log(new Date().getTime() - start); };
```

The resulting output will likely be 0. That's 0 milliseconds. What does this tell us about the execution time of an arbitrary method?

Yes JavaScript is single-threaded. Yes it's synchronous. So the ***fact*** is that one method will always call before the other, despite them coming in at the same time.

However, the response times will be *'pretty'* accurate so long as the callbacks don't bottleneck the scripts execution. As I said, it depends what you call ***'acurate'***.

***Another Edit!***

Dang it. I've just noticed your `//some task that takes 5 seconds` comment is possibly referring to a long synchronous task? If you are saying that the process will execute for 5 seconds, synchronously, then yes - accuracy will be an issue here.

Comment: "JavaScript still executes synchronously."  So, while callback1 is executing, ajax2 returns and calls callback2. But callback2 can't execute because JS is single threaded and waiting for callback1 to finish.  Callback2 finally gets its chance to execute, but 5 seconds has already passed...so timing is off by 5 seconds.

Comment: @Alex No, the time that each `success` method is called is (for most processors) less than a millisecond. The initial `$.ajax` calls are less than a millisecond apart. The `success` callbacks are exactly that: methods to call once the `$.ajax` is complete.

Comment: the success methods are callbacks, that aren't called until the ajax call completes successfully.  You can't say they are executed a millisecond apart, it depends on how long it took to get the response back.

Comment: @Alex Yes, sorry, I worded it badly. What I'm saying is that the methods themselves are executed within a matter of milliseconds when they are called. I don't mean they will be called milliseconds after one another - as you say, that would depend on the response time of the ajax request.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to get response times, accurately.  So am i correct that the execution time of the first success callback would be figured into the 2nd callback, and therefore NOT be accurate?

Comment: The only case where it would be incorrect is if they both complete at about the same time. Obviously, to remedy that, simply delay one of them so that that can't happen. Note however that the correct way to test this would be to not use the browser at all, and instead use a tool such as fiddler or a server-side language.

Comment: @Alex Well they would be accurate by milliseconds' standards. It depended how much processing you were doing within each callback. How much accuracy do you need? It's true to say that if both ajax requests responded at EXACTLY the same time, JavaScript would process one before the other, yes.

Comment: @shennan, in my question I put the comment "task that takes 5 seconds."  So based on your answer, then no the timing would not be accurate.  And I would have to use deferred calls.  Thanks Shennan.

Comment: @Alex the term 'accuracy' depends on the context. How much ***resolution*** do you want? In your idea of accuracy, can we assume that `0 millieseconds === 0 millieseconds` resolves to `true`? Or would this also be considered unresolved?

Comment: down to milliseconds is good enough :)   I posted an answer to considered the execution times of other callbacks